Image onload just loads first image in array
Updated with the media array.
I need to get the width and height of som media (images and videos).
I am using a for loop and onload/eventlistner to get this, but if I have more then one media of the same kind, I only get the data of the first one. (I have to use old javascript so no foreach because it will not be used in an ordinary browser)
var imgSrc = 'fallBack.png';
var imgType = 'photo';
var screenW = document.body.clientWidth;
var screenH = document.body.clientHeight;

images = [
  {media: { type: "photo", media: "image1.png" }},
  {media: { type: "photo", media: "image1.png" }}
]
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
       console.log(this); // this just shows for the first image in the list with two images

    //Simplefying what I want out of this
    If(this.width < this.height && screenW < screenH) {
      imgSrc = this.src;
      imgType = "photo"
     };


You're storing each new Image object you are creating in the same variable, so you effectively only have one image with an actual load handler attached here. Push them into an array instead.

"Old JavaScript?" Array.forEach is supported since IE10 - where/when is screen.backgroundMedia.type from? What is the platform you are using?

Also: Where does length come from? Where do you set the image's source? (A complete [mre] is always helpful)

The code works perfectly fine for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/06y4f9xz/ problably something else is wrong.

this just shows for the first image how? you aren't loading any images

I updated the code a bit now, realizing the problem could be the media object. This is not going to be used in an ordinary browser and some is only supporting old javascript (so no const and foreach)

your code defines images but only ever uses images.length ... how can their be a problem with "the media object" (which looks suspiciously like a string)

You are missing img.src = images[i].media.media

Here is a version that counts the loads and displays when done


var images = [
  {media: { type: "photo", media: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549778399-f94fd24d4697?q=80&w=2574&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" }},
  {media: { type: "photo", media: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547628641-ec2098bb5812?q=80&w=2670&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" }}
],
len = images.length,
count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].media.image = new Image();
  images[i].media.image.onload = function() {
    images[i].media.dimensions = {
      w: this.width,
      h: this.height
    };
    count++; 
    console.log(this.width < this.height); // whatever you need here
    if (count === len) {
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
  };
  images[i].media.image.src = images[i].media.media;
}




Thanks, this worked.
When using video´s I had to add the src to my video to be able to get the onloadedmetadata to work.
images[i].media.video = document.createElement("VIDEO");
images[i].media.video.src = images[i].media.media;

Just create an array and store the images into it.
Additionally, removed setTimeout and added a simple counter loadedImagesCount and checkAllImagesLoaded which checks if the counter is equal to the size of images.


var imgSrc = 'fallback.png';
var imgType = 'photo';
var screenW = document.body.clientWidth;
var screenH = document.body.clientHeight;

var images = [{
    media: {
      type: "photo",
      media: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    }
  },
  {
    media: {
      type: "photo",
      media: "https://via.placeholder.com/200"
    }
  },
  {
    media: {
      type: "photo",
      media: "https://via.placeholder.com/250"
    }
  }
];

var imagesArray = [];
var loadedImagesCount = 0;

function checkAllImagesLoaded() {
  if (loadedImagesCount === images.length) {
    console.log("All images loaded:", imagesArray);

    // Logic after all images are loaded:
    for (var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
      var img = imagesArray[i];
      console.log("Image " + i + ": " + img.src + " is " + img.width + "x" + img.height);

      if (img.width < img.height && screenW < screenH) {
        imgSrc = img.src;
        imgType = images[i].media.type;
      }
    }

  }
}

// Load images and update counter
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      imagesArray[index] = img;
      loadedImagesCount++;
      checkAllImagesLoaded();
    };
    img.src = images[index].media.media;
  })(i);
}




your setTimeout approach is naive ... one of those images took more than 3 seconds to load for me

@JaromandaX correct! I did not take that into account previously, now it should work better.

This locks like a good solution as well, I used the other one because it worked better for me. Thanks for the help :)

@Joe it is actually similar solution, but I used the function instead of checking it inline.
